# Counting and then removing duplicates from email list

Tags: python, count, duplicates

I have a long list of email addresses (8000) sorted alphabetically but there are duplicates.

With python - how can I count the number of recurrences of a unique email (count duplicates) and while maintaining one instance of the email delete the recurring duplicate emails from the list.

example list:

```
a@sample.com
b@sample.com
b@sample.com
b@sample.com
c@sample.com
c@sample.com
```

results:

```
a@sample.com (1)
b@sample.com (3)
c@sample.com (2)
```

I've searched online, but only find methods of removing duplicate numbers, dictionaries and tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.groupby()` for alphabetical sorted order:-

```
 >>>l = list of emails 
 >>>[(key, sum(1 for _ in group)) for key, group in groupby(sorted(l))]

[('a@sample.com', 1), ('b@sample.com', 3), ('c@sample.com', 2)]
```

Use `collections.Counter` to count the items that are duplicate.

```
>>>from collections import Counter
>>>d = Counter(['a@sample.com',
>>>'b@sample.com',
>>>'b@sample.com',
>>>'b@sample.com',
>>>'c@sample.com',
>>>'c@sample.com'])
>>>d
```

Output:-

```
Counter({'b@sample.com': 3, 'c@sample.com': 2, 'a@sample.com': 1})
```

It is similar to(or in simplest way)

```
d = {}
for i in l: # l = list or all emails.
    if i in d:
        d[i] += 1
    else:
        d[i] = 1
```

or use `dict.get` 
    for i in l:
        d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1

Comment: `d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1` is a better idiom.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_email
['a@sample.com', 'b@sample.com', 'b@sample.com', 'b@sample.com', 'c@sample.com', 'c@sample.com\n']
>>> Counter(my_email)
Counter({'b@sample.com': 3, 'c@sample.com': 2, 'a@sample.com': 1})
```

if you want in order:

```
>>> sorted(Counter(my_email).items())
[('a@sample.com', 1), ('b@sample.com', 3), ('c@sample.com', 2)]
```

you can print like this:

```
>>> for x in sorted(Counter(my_email).items()):
...     print x[0],x[1]   # if you sung python 3 print(x[0],x[1])
... 
a@sample.com 1
b@sample.com 3
c@sample.com 2
```

Comment: Subsequent sort is required. However, 8000 entries are nothing before built-in sort.

Comment: If you're going to sort based on keys then the `key` call is useless, a dict always has unique keys.

Comment: yea right, its useless